# How do I run a VBA macro stored inside a workbook without opening it?

Tags: python, vba, excel

Suppose I have a workbook called `trigger.xlsm` that stores a macro that would traverse through all the other workbooks under the same directory where `trigger.xlsm` is located, and transformed them somehow.

I can definitely open `trigger.xlsm`, and run the macro. But I feel like there is no need one should first open `trigger.xlsm`. Can I run the macro without opening `trigger.xlsm`? Or maybe I can change `trigger.xlsm` into a `trigger.exe` file and simply click the `trigger.exe` file?

If I have to resolve to any other programming languages such as Python (I am more comfortable with Python) to accomplish this, what third party packages are recommended?

*BTW, this is a question on the design of automation, if you have any other ideas rather than using a .exe file, also feel free to let me know!*

Comment: If you put the code in your personal.xlsb it would not do the job for you? If the code is used by multiple users, it would not be the solution

Comment: From your question and a comment to someone's answer, it sounds like you want to run an Excel macro without an Excel application object of any sort?  Is that correct?

Comment: you can make a VBS file and have the windows scheduler run it for you if not yourself

Comment: @Ibo You have to open personal.xlsb, right? But I just like to click something (say, button, a .exe, whatever), then it manipulates the other workbooks.

Comment: @Nicholas you can easily create buttons and/or a tab in the ribbon, have macros defined and assigned to them, simply open the Excel to see the ribbon and then click any button you need to run something, the code will take care of everything. You just need to launch Excel to have access to the ribbon tabs

Comment: @YowE3K I just feel like the trigger.xlsm is redundant, not to mention opening it before running the macro inside. Usually, a .exe file should be enough.

Comment: Depending on how much your code is and what kind of actions it take you can simply convert it to a VBS file (open a txt file, write your codes there, change the extension to vbs). The VBS file can also be 2-3 line, open you trigger.xlsm to run a code inside of it, after being done, close trigger.xlsm. It will be like an exe file, there is no need for an exe file

Comment: Saying "I want to run Excel VBA code without an Excel application" is a bit like saying "I want to run a program without a CPU chip".  You need the Excel application to process the code, just like you would need a CPU to process the instructions in an EXE.  (Note:  The Excel Application object doesn't have to include the Excel GUI, but the Application has to be there.)

Comment: @YowE3K Then is there a `.Excel-based-exe` format that goes directly to the macro inside and runs it without opening the Excel GUI? Why should one see the GUI (Excel application interface) to run macro if GUI has never been important to the user?

Comment: The macro is not in machine language - it gets "compiled" (by the Excel Application) on an as required basis.  So the GUI can be made invisible, but the Application is necessary to do the "compilation".

Comment: @YowE3K Then how do I convert the macro to after-complied-code into a .exe or whatever format that I don't need to open the application anymore? My point is actually pretty simple: you don't need to open something to run something, just run something.

Comment: @YowE3K Can I open Excel application and compile my macro and turn it into another type of file, then only keep this format of file and run it in the future?

Comment: @Nicholas a VBScript file will do the job then, windows will run it for you and there is no need to open Excel application. See how: http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/

Comment: @Ibo - unless the OP translates the macro into something that doesn't require access to the functions within the Excel Application object, even a VBScript will need to create a reference to the Excel Application.

Comment: I know of no automated way to convert an Excel macro into an EXE (or similar) that does not require access to the Excel Application object.  (Another analogy - imagine having some .Net source code, but no compiler, and no .Net Framework installed.  What would you do to run that code?  Even if you got a compiler somewhere, you would still need a replacement for the Framework.)

Comment: @Ibo This is better except that there is a *redundant* .xlsm file. So if you share the file to others, you actually give them two files: the .vbs (the one you double click to manipulate workbooks) and  the .xlsm (the one .vbs calls the macro from).

Comment: @YowE3K No need to be an *automated* way to convert an Excel macro into an EXE, a manual way is enough. But I think I understand your idea now, basically my .exe (low-level code) has to also create an Excel compiler, essentially. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @Nicholas as I said, you can use ONLY vbs file, you just need to put all of your code in the vbs file. The trigger.xlsm file will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way through Excel without creating an `exe` would be to create a `Office.Interop` add-in. There is a `startup` event with which you can reference `VBA` code and do a `Run("nameOfYourMacro")`.

And if you're looking for a python replacement [here's the same question](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Python-libraries-most-useful-for-manipulating-Excel-spreadsheets). I particularly like Parfait Gasana's answer there and will probably be most beneficial for you.

Comment: Please note that I don't want start Excel, I just don't need to open any Excel to run the macro.

Comment: The second option is essentially equal to running an `exe` but you can keep your code. Otherwise, I'd say just create an `exe` if you want nothing to do with Excel... *HOWEVER* if you're going to edit the documents using `Office.Interop` libraries, you might as well open Excel because the libraries will create an instance of Excel anyways. At which point, other 3rd party libraries are faster but you're going to have to change all your code probably if performance is key.

Comment: In your post it just sounded like you just didn't want to open the `.xlsm`, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that, if the `.xlsm` file is placed in Excel's startup folder, the file will be opened every time Excel is opened.

Comment: I don't use macro-enabled Word files much (at all?) but I suspect it is the same - anything in the Startup directory is just loaded automatically at startup.

Comment: @YowE3K No, in Word you never see the macro-document actually open but it loads the code in behind. So, a little different. Granted, it still "opens" the file but you never see it and you don't see multiple instances of Word in Task Manager. It attaches to your Word instance somehow I assume.

Comment: Also, I would never suggest writing any macros in Word unless you want to cry yourself to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your macros on `Workbook_Open()` event. You can open that workbook with this code.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = true

'<~assuming the file to be opened is in the same folder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objpath = fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\[NameOfWorkbook].xlsx"
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objpath)
```

Paste this in notepad and save it (in the same folder as your workbook) with `.vbs` file extension.